# Not being able to lookup transform leading to node's death in building point cloud

Tags: transform, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to build a point cloud using pose information. The code snippet for that is as below:

```
static tf::TransformBroadcaster tfb;
tf::Transform xform;
xform.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(pose3D_LD2.pose.position.x, pose3D_LD2.pose.position.y, pose3D_LD2.pose.position.z));
xform.setRotation(tf::Quaternion(previous_poseLD_.pose.orientation.x, previous_poseLD_.pose.orientation.y, previous_poseLD_.pose.orientation.z, previous_poseLD_.pose.orientation.w));
tfb.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(xform, ros::Time(pose3D_LD2.header.stamp), "/base_link", "/laser"));
tfListener_.waitForTransform("/base_link", "/laser", ros::Time(0), ros::Duration(2.0));
projector_.transformLaserScanToPointCloud("/base_link", previous_scan_, cloud, tfListener_);
```

However, I receive this error message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'tf::ExtrapolationException'
what():  Unable to lookup transform, cache is empty, when looking up transform from frame [/laser] to frame [/base_link]
[pointcloud_builder_node-5] process has died [pid 13012, exit code -6].
```

what could be the error that leads to the death of the node as stated in the error message? Or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I've also tried to comment last 2 lines of the above code snippet which are disabling waitForTransform and transformLaserScanToPointCloud calls, and watching the output up to calling sendTransform. It gives a warning like below:

```
[ WARN] [1327489676.295791909]: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame /laser at time 24.279 according to authority /pointcloud_builder_node
Possible reasons are listed at 
[ WARN] [1327489676.628911299]: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame /laser at time 24.328 according to authority /pointcloud_builder_node
Possible reasons are listed at 
[ WARN] [1327489676.962231439]: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame /laser at time 24.348 according to authority /pointcloud_builder_node
Possible reasons are listed at
```

Any remedy for this kind of error?

UPDATE:

```
static tf::TransformBroadcaster tfb;
tf::Transform xform;
xform.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(pose3D_LD2.pose.position.x, pose3D_LD2.pose.position.y, pose3D_LD2.pose.position.z));
xform.setRotation(tf::Quaternion(previous_poseLD_.pose.orientation.x, previous_poseLD_.pose.orientation.y, previous_poseLD_.pose.orientation.z, previous_poseLD_.pose.orientation.w));
tfb.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(xform, ros::Time(pose3D_LD2.header.stamp), "base_link", "laser"));
tfListener_.waitForTransform("base_link", "laser", previous_scan_.header.stamp, ros::Duration(2.0));
projector_.transformLaserScanToPointCloud("base_link", previous_scan_, cloud, tfListener_);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12746/not-being-able-to-lookup-transform-leading-to-node%27s-death-in-building-point-cloud/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-01-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where is your point cloud coming from? If it is a rosbag, try setting the parameter use_sim_time to true and playing it back with `rosbag play --clock <bag>`. If it's an actual sensor, is it maybe connected to a different computer and the clocks are not synchronized?

Another, more dirty solution would be to set previous_scan_.header.stamp to ros::Time::now(). Also, make sure that pose3D_LD2.header.stamp and previous_scan_.header.stamp are equal. If not, you need at least two transforms, one before the stamp of your scan and one after it. TF needs to do interpolation if it doesn't have an exact time stamp for which it needs two transforms.

Btw. your waitForTransform call shouldn't use ros::Time(0) but previous_scan_.header.stamp.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-27**:
@Lorenz: When you have time, could you please have a look at this one (http://answers.ros.org/question/3756/scan-lines-are-not-gathered-in-generating-a-point)

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-25**:
@Lorenz: If you have time, could you please guide me on this time-related issue (http://answers.ros.org/question/3731/exception-problem-that-is-related-to-time-issue). So far, i found you are among the best in dealing with time-related issue.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-25**:
@Lorenz: You've given me a great guide about time-related issue in which I was stuck for  a long time..@DimitriProsser: You've contributed to using the try-and-catch block that is also essential for this problem. However, I can only tick one for the right answer, even both of yours are the clues.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-01-25**:
What did you do so that I can update my answer to be more helpful for others?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-25**:
It now works! Thanks a lot..

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-01-25**:
Ok. then maybe the frame_ids don't match. Try waitForTransform("/base_link", previous_scan_.header.frame_id, previous_scan_.header.stamp, ros::Duration(2.0));

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-25**:
Following what you have suggested "if (!waitForTransform(...)) ..", it enters the "else" block, and certainly not returning the "Unable to transform"..

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-01-25**:
It is clear that transformLaserScanToPointCloud throws the exception since it is the only method that does the tf lookup. But what is the return value of waitForTransform? Are you sure that it is really true, not false?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-25**:
Thanks a lot Lorenz, yeah, I've just updated it as above.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-01-25**:
Can you update the code in the question to match your code again? How does the waitForTransform line look now and how does the transformLaserScanToPointCloud look now?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-25**:
I've run the checker or exception handling that you suggested. It's then sure now that up to waitForTransform is okay, meaning the transform is OK. Only the last line of transformLaserScanToPointCloud is the tricky part now..

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-01-25**:
Just do something like: if (!waitForTransform(...)) { ROS_ERROR("Unable to transform"); } else { projector_.transformLaserScanToPointCloud(...); } to prevent the exception. Increasing the timeout will probably not help. Make sure that the time stamps of previous_scan_ and pose3D_LD2 are equal.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-25**:
Do you mean, I should increase it, instead of using 2 seconds?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-01-25**:
Note that you don't actually check if waitForTransform actually succeeded. In your call with timeout 2 seconds, it will return false if no transform could be found. In that case, transformlaserScanToPointCloud will fail.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-25**:
This time, up to waitForTransform, it returns no error, but when it comes to transformLaserScanToPointCloud call, then, it's dead.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-25**:
I'm again trying to revert but still not getting it..

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-25**:
After editing some lines of code, I've again obtained this kind of error.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-25**:
@Lorenz: The follow-up question is here if you can guide me on this: http://answers.ros.org/question/3715/cloud-values-are-not-loaded

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-24**:
Thanks a lot Lorenz, that works for this problem. However, the point cloud is not working yet. Your last line saved me.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is that you're not wrapping these functions:

```
tfListener_.waitForTransform("/base_link", "/laser", ros::Time(0), ros::Duration(2.0));
projector_.transformLaserScanToPointCloud("/base_link", previous_scan_, cloud, tfListener_);
```

in  a `try/catch` block. Both of these operations throw a transform exception that you must catch. This will not solve the problem that is cause the exception, but it will prevent your program from exiting every time one is received. Try the following:

```
try
{
    tfListener_.waitForTransform("/base_link", "/laser", ros::Time(0), ros::Duration(2.0));
    projector_.transformLaserScanToPointCloud("/base_link", previous_scan_, cloud, tfListener_);
}
catch (tf::TransformException e)
{
    ROS_WARN("My_node: %s", ex.what());
}
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-01-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-27**:
@DimitriProsser: If you have time, could you please have a look at this one (http://answers.ros.org/question/3756/scan-lines-are-not-gathered-in-generating-a-point)

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-01-26**:
The laser projection class fails to catch the exception thrown by tf. It does not throw an exception of its own. You're just catching the exception that it is probably supposed to catch.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-25**:
But then, here(http://www.ros.org/doc/api/laser_geometry/html/classlaser__geometry_1_1LaserProjection.html), it says nothing about throwing of exception by LaserProjection.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-25**:
Thanks anyway..

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-01-25**:
ros.org/wiki/tf for general documentation on tf. The API docs as well as tutorials are then linked on the right.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-25**:
@Lorenz and @DimitriProsser: Could you point me to the API docs that shows those throwing exceptions..Any link.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-01-25**:
My bad. But you can put the waitForTransform() call outside of the try/catch if you want to. It will work exactly the same way.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-01-25**:
waitForTransform does *not* throw tf exceptions according to the API docs. Only lookup functions throw TF exceptions. I would call this solution actually a workaround. It is not clear to me why sometimes waitForTransform seems to succeed while transformLaserScanToPointCloud fails.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-25**:
Thanks a lot for the explanation. That answers why a lot of crashes I experienced before when dealing with the tf lookup functions.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-01-25**:
Well, it's not quite a "workaround". All of ROS's tf lookup functions throw exceptions when they're not able to do perform the requested operation. In C++, if you fail to catch an exception, it will crash your program. Basically, you should always wrap tf lookups in a try/catch block.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-25**:
@DimitriProsser: Thanks a lot..It's really a great help. But I still do not understand why these 2 lines need to be in the try/catch block. As they are running sequentially, it should be OK, in my opinion. But your workaround is right here.